# Metro add additional classes for marshalling

Tags: java, marshalling, java-metro-framework

I've got a very generic wsdl which I cannot change. I generated stubs for the given wsdl using Metro. One of the stub parameter objects accept's a list of objects, which is the generic part of this wsdl.
The content of this list is an XML represented as String, which must not be escaped. I've got a schema for this XML and generated classes using jaxb (the same classes as metro will generate, since it's using jaxb as well). Now if I do something like this

```
Startup startup = new Startup();
startup.getContent().add(myGeneratedJaxBObject);
getStub().someMethod(startup);
```

I will get an error that myGeneratedObject cannot be marshalled, since the classes are not known to the JaxB context of the stub. Is there a way to make my classes part of the stub?